# Can I avoid Terramorphous' Blackhole/Wormhole Thresher attack?

Tags: borderlands-2

Today I met Terramorphous' Wormhole thresher attack. It is not pleasant; we took constant damage, were unable to move fast enough to escape the pull of the vortex (he pulls you in like a wormhole thresher) and he didn't summon any tentacles. His attack animation (and the gravity pull) stopped just after our Fight for your Life timers started to run out (it was *extremely* long, a minute or two), and with no tentacles to kill for second winds we all quickly died.

Is there anything we can do to avoid/escape from his blackhole attack? "Die and pray for a tentacle to kill" didn't work so well.

Comment: he stays underground for a long time with dust rising from the same position before he does that attack. at least, that was my experience.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A late answer but for anyone curious, once you are pulled in whether you don't know when it's coming and can't find cover quick enough or you just do not focus on the health, completely understandable, there are a few tricks you can perform.

***Take note, this move often occurs around 15-30% health region. Terramorphous will also become extremely vulnerable to attacks at this stage as well.***

Of course the character you are is the most dependent on what you choose to do, assuming you are level 48-50, otherwise just leave... anyway these are the best methods I could advise you to do whether it be solo or 4 player co-op.

Zer0: If not already adjusted, adjust Zer0's skills points into "Bloodshed" as deception mode is fantastic! Throwing Kunai is also a nice bit of help. Also wield a weapon, usually a magnum (Often called the Law?), or something like that with an under-barrel blade allowing you an additional 100% damage approximately. Once being pulled in activate deception mode early IF you have Kunai, and pelt with Kunai whilst ensuring you have the bladed magnum (Law?) equipped ready to being melee attacking, non-stop. Once touching Terramorphous unleash your deception mode enhanced, additional melee damage and skill enhanced melee attacks into him, bringing his health down rather rapidly, from the state it's in. **In brief: Equip bladed weapon, slasher time.**

Axton: Just ensure that Axton can throw down his Sabre turret and do your damn best to stand behind the turret as this can work like the rocks at the back of the area, helpful because the rocks can't hold 4 people, not even 2 in my experience, you kinda just keep fighting each other for the spot... Anyhow, keep blasting away while your turret acts as another player causing damage and hope for the best that you do not get pulled in too early, as Axton is one of this most difficult players to be at this time. **In brief: Drop a turret, gun it down.**

Maya: She is extremely useful throughout this entire fight keeping herself and other protected whilst making Terramorphous more vulnerable to all attacks, assuming the skill tree has been adjusted. During this wormhole part, using Mayas ability can actually reduce the damage taken from being in contact with Terramorphous, depending on what part of Terramorphous you are touching, but again, use the ability to weaken Terramorphous and spray her down. **In brief: Cause giant bubble, pop giant bubble.**

Salvador: Could there be a more obvious option with him? Spray, spray, spray, spray, spray and maybe roar while doing it. Your options are very limited with this character, for the simple matter he is a f@#&ing psychopathic animal, eating machine! Just make sure you equip two good weapon choices for this final moment, probably launchers with large clips size around 4-8 shots in each clip as this final part shouldn't take long.
**In brief: Gunzerk, Don't miss**

I unfortunately can't help any further as I have not used the Mechromancer or Psycho but would imagine they are of better use as DLC character usually have some over power form to them. Hope this has helped and if not, go talk to Claptrap, he will make me more persuasive. ENJOY!

Comment: Completely welcome, happy to help! Feel free to inform me with any other difficulties on perhaps other games you encounter later on.

Answer (score 3):

Before he starts the wormhole attack, hide behind a rock. He will pull you, but the rock will block you, for the most part. But if you're exposed once he starts the attack, you're pretty much hosed.

If you're hidden for most of the attack, but he manages to pull you around it, or you accidently leave the protection of the rock, you can resist—a little—by running the other direction. But that will only help you if you managed to stay behind the rock long enough that he doesn't have time to pull you all the way to him before his attack ends. Because once you're next to him, you're pretty much dead.

Comment: That was my theory, good to know it works. Is there a way to tell when he's doing to do it? By the time I realized he was doing the wormhole attack I was starting to get pulled in, but since I've only seen it once I might have missed some visual/other cue before the attack.

Comment: @BenBrocka: I thought about mentioning the fact that, no, I don't know if the boss has a tell before that move or not. Does anyone else here know if the boss has one or not, and if so what it is?

Answer (score 1):

The turret shield skill Negates the blackhole effect. Basically, he doesn't pull you in as long as you stay inside the shield.

Answer (score 0):

The commandos turret(with the turrets shield skill)will block the wormhole if it is between you and him while he's doing the attack

Answer (score 0):

As a gunzerker, you can survive being directly next to him if you have a moxxi's grog nozzle and another weapon that can pump out enough damage to heal you if you are gunzerking. If you're not when the attack starts, you can walk backwards to delay it long enough to start 'zerking again. This doesn't help you escape it but it should let you survive it. Hope it helps!